# Azure AD app authentication complexity with using Certificate?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My organization is thinking for now to use 'Client Secret' authentication for service principal instead of using Certificate for the sake of simplicity. However, we need to list down complexities involved using certificate.
Could anyone share some info with me?
I did some Googling but unable to find the most relevant info.

Note that we'd be using Certificates going forward as recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Using a certificate to obtain a token is much more complicated than using a shared secret.

For **client_secret**, it only requires you to directly **New client secret** in the azure portal, but for [**certificate credentials**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) you must first associate the certificate credentials with the client application in the Microsoft Identity Platform by **uploading the certificate file** on the Azure portal or **updating the application manifest**. Next, An assertion (a JWT) that you need to create and sign with the certificate you registered as credentials for your application.

However, compared to shared secrets, certificate credentials do provide a higher level of assurance.

Comment: Thanks Carl. All we are trying to do here is to access Online MS Exchange using OAuth 2.0 and update the user's calendar